# luamplib creates unexpected files

Tags: luatex, metapost

I compile the following file `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{mplibcode}
input metauml;
beginfig(1);
  Note.xxx("Hello");
  drawObjects(xxx);
  endfig;
  end
bye
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex -recorder test`.
The problem occurs also with no recorder option.

What I face are a lot of files in the local folder
all of the form `luamplib_input_metauml*_mp` but all empty.

When I open `test.fls` then I observe lines like the following:

```
INPUT /usr/share/texmf/metapost/metauml/metauml.mp
OUTPUT                 ./luamplib_input_metauml_mp
...
INPUT /usr/share/texmf/metapost/metauml/util_object.mp
OUTPUT                 ./luamplib_input_util_object_mp
```

This seems part of the explanation: `lualatex` seems to load several files tied  with metauml but no idea why it writes those mysterious files.

Some hint is in the luamplib documentation: from the documentation

```
local function replaceinputmpfile (name,file)
167 local ofmodify = lfsattributes(file,”modification”)
168 if not ofmodify then return file end
169 local cachedir = luamplib.cachedir or outputdir
170 local newfile = name:gsub(”%W”,”_”)
171 newfile = cachedir ..”/luamplib_input_”..newfile   <-----------
172 if newfile and luamplibtime then
173 local nf = lfsattributes(newfile)
174 if nf and nf.mode == ”file” and
175 ofmodify == nf.modification and luamplibtime < nf.access then
176 return nf.size == 0 and file or newfile
177 end
178 end
```

I think this could be lua... can anyone tell me what happens here
and how can I avoid these files in the local directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows?  Mac?  Something else?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by this one.  On my mac, the only files included in `.fls` with the `-recorder` option are files directly used by the tex part of the process.  Files included inside the mplib environment with `input` are not written to `.fls` -- you can see them in the `.log` file if you have `\mplibshowlog{enable}` but nowhere else.  So on my mac at least, I cannot re-create your problem.  But I *guess* it is something to do with luatex's cache management, and I *guess* that it does not have the correct permissions to update/delete any cached files.

Comment: @thruston something else: suse linux. To be honest, my working computer, windows behaves differently... It does not recognize dependencies, but this is another story. 
In both cases we talk about texlive.

Comment: @thurston, Hm, i suspect also that it has to do with access rights. 
I think, the problem is that he has no cachedir. If it has it writes all these files in the cachedir. 

So i dont think the difference in behavior really has to do with the operating system.

I would like to remark, that i think that dependencies shall occur in the fls file. 
If not, this undertermines the depencency mechanism as input command in metapost introduce further dependencies.

Comment: *I would like to remark, that i think that dependencies shall occur in the fls file.* 
Maybe they should, but as far as I can observe, they do not.

*If not, this undermines the dependency mechanism as input command in metapost introduce further dependencies*
True -- maybe you should raise a feature request with the luatex team?

Comment: In the meantime I reached someone from the package maintainers. 
Lets see how it goes on.

Answer (score 1):

There is some amount of confusion here. I hope this clears things up:

1. luamplib does not currently record file i/o performed by mplib (i.e. `input` statements in metapost code). Support for this was only added yesterday, in [this commit](https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/commit/48aea5c980893addb7df8371914c2515d03fa0ef).
2. The (many) files you see output in the `.fls` file are created by luamplib (not metapost/mplib) in order to support `btex...etex;` statements (see the luamplib manual, page three, under ‘Settings regarding cache files’).
3. I am a bit surprised this mechanism is still present, because for a few years now, `btex...etex;` can be supported directly with the metapost `maketext` primitive and the lua `tex.runtoks()` function (and so it is, indeed, by luamplib). This may be something you should ask the luamplib maintainers about, of which I am not one.
4. The location of these files can be changed with the `$TEXMFVAR` environment variable, or more specifically with `\mplibcachedir{<directory path>}`. (The setting of the former environment variable is indeed likely to be the only relevant difference between your two installations.)

If the cache files really bother you, and if this is indeed meant as a stand-alone metapost graphic, you could consider using the (experimental) minim-lamp format (from the [minim-mp](https://ctan.org/pkg/minim-mp) package) instead of luamplib. Take the following steps.

1. create the file `test.mp` with contents:

```
verbatimtex
\usepackage{fontspec}
etex;

input metauml;

beginfig(1);
  Note.xxx("Hello");
  drawObjects(xxx);
endfig;

bye
```

2. Note that any latex preambule contents go into the `verbatimtex...etex;` part.
3. Create the format file, as it is not enabled by default in texlive:

```
$ luatex --ini minim-lamp.ini
```

4. This create the file `minim-lamp.fmt`, which can now be used to turn luatex into a stand-alone metapost processor like so:

```
$ luatex --fmt minim-lamp test.mp
```

5. The `.mp` extension must be present on the command line. The result is a pdf file with every figure on a page of its own.
6. The `--recorder` option is not currently supported by minim-mp either, but [will be](https://gitlab.com/renkema/minim/-/commit/16d034b10f4dfe22be575ca5e5e4e3a42c3add02#af0765e8e534d4e972f10b18eddac38c08968037) in the next version.

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure, I should probably note that I am the author of minim-mp.

Comment: I learned a lot.. Thank you. I will try both